# GraphicsGrid with a Label for each Column and Row

Tags: graphics, visualization

Is it possible to use GraphicsGrid and do something like this?

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{X} & Label1 & Label2& Label3\\ 
Label4 & Plot1 & Plot2&Plot3\\
Label5 & Plot4 & Plot5&Plot6\\
Label6 & Plot7 & Plot8&Plot9\\
\end{array} $

Answer (score 8):

Here is an option:

```
plots = Table[Table[Plot[Sin[i x + j], {x, 1, 10}], {i, 3}], {j, 3}];
xlabels = {"", "Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"};
ylabels = {"Label 4", "Label 5", "Label 6"};
GraphicsGrid[Join[{xlabels}, Transpose[Join[{ylabels}, Transpose[plots]]]]]
```

[image]

Updated with a slightly prettier option:

```
xlabels = Text[Style[#, Large]] & /@ {"", "Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"};
ylabels = Text[Style[#, Large]] & /@ {"Label 4", "Label 5", "Label 6"};
Grid[Join[{xlabels}, Transpose[Join[{ylabels}, Transpose[plots]]]], Spacings -> {2, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to forego `GraphicsGrid` and give up some control over the placement of the decorations, it can be as simple as this:

Make a 3 x 3 array of graphics (this is adopted from a [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192112/3066)}

```
circles[n_] :=
  Module[{r, cntr}, 
    r := RandomReal[.25];
    cntr := RandomReal[1, {2}];
    Graphics[Table[{EdgeForm[Black], Hue[RandomReal[]], Disk[cntr, r]}, n], 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, Frame -> True]

lines[] := 
  Module[{lf, rt}, 
    lf := With[{x = RandomReal[.48]}, {Red, Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}]}];
    rt := With[{x = RandomReal[{.52, 1}]}, {Blue, Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}]}];
    Graphics[{lf, rt}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, Frame -> True]]

SeedRandom[4];
graphics =
  Apply[
    Show, 
    Partition[Transpose[{Table[circles[8], 9], Table[lines[], 9]}], 3], 
    {2}];
```

Make the headers:

```
{colHeaders, rowHeaders} = Partition[Table[Style[Row[{"Label", i}], "TBI"], {i, 6}], 3];
```

Make the grid with `TableForm`:

```
TableForm[graphics, TableHeadings -> {rowHeaders, colHeaders}]
```

[image: grid]

Answer (score 3):

You could construct `Graphics` for the row and column headings. Something like this. Would have to adjust the vertical / horizontal placement of the label text.

```
plotGrid = Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 2, 2];

plotRowHeader = 
 Table[Graphics[Style[Text["Label " <> ToString[i]], 12]], {i, 2}];

plotColumnHeader = 
  Table[Graphics[Style[Text["Label " <> ToString[i]], 12]], {i, 3, 
     4}] // Prepend[Graphics[Style[Text["X"], 12]]];

graphicsGrid = 
  plotGrid // Prepend[plotRowHeader] // Transpose // 
   Prepend[plotColumnHeader];

GraphicsGrid[graphicsGrid]
```

[image]